# indices of the constant array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm following doubts, have a date in string format, turned it on in php date format, then turned into a multidimensional array, but the array indices are always the same, all within while, example below.

```
$string = "20102015";
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC'); 
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $string, $timezone); 
$arr = array($dateTime->format('d/m/Y'));
print_r($arr); 

/*  Result:
Array ( [0] => 23/10/2015 )
Array ( [0] => 22/11/2015 ) 
Array ( [0] => 21/11/2015 ) 
Array ( [0] => 15/10/2015 ) 
Array ( [0] => 29/10/2015 )
*/
```

Comment: You're creating just one array, with one value. Share in your question what you're after getting.

Answer (score 0):

`$arr = array($dateTime->format('d/m/y));` will assign a new value into $arr, i.e. not appending it.

If you place this in a while loop, you're simply repeating the assignment.

If you're trying to generate a list of dates, try instead:

```
$arr = [];
while(...) {
  $string = "20102015"; // I assume something changes this in the loop
  $timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC'); 
  $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $string, $timezone);
  $arr[] = $dateTime->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are only taking a single string date value and casting it as an array (which gives you a numerically indexed array with a single value in it, not a multi-dimensional array).

You do this the same way with each iteration.  Each time you cast the string to a single member array.  The index of that string within the array will be `0` every time.

If you are trying to build an array of all the values from each iteration you are probably after this:

```
// assign value to next index in existing array
$arr[] = $dateTime->format('d/m/Y');
```